# External link doesnt work in FF, Chrome but works in IE 9

Tags: c#, jquery, html, browser

I need to add an external link on my website for live scoring but for some security reason itftennis.com block link embedding on external website.

If you click on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8H7e/2/) LIVE SCORING link it with open page with error but if you click on the address bar and then click enter link will work or if you type this link direct in address bar then it will work

[Click here](http://scores.itftennis.com/?alias=itf&layoutid=72&versionid=1&language=en&tID=W-C50-FRA-05A-2013)  this wont work.

Is there some way around using jQuery to make this link work.

I am sure they are check the link source reference and once it is outside their domain they block it may be they want users to visit their website inorder to view live scoring..

Any help in this regard is appreciate. This is not a pure programing question but i am looking for some sort of jquery or C# based solution to make this link work.. on other website

```
 function launchPCLiveScores() {
     window.open('http://scores.itftennis.com/?alias=itf&layoutid=72&versionid=1&language=en&tID=W-C50-FRA-05A-2013', 'ITFProCircuitLiveScore', 'width=1000,height=700');
 }
```

**UPDATED**:

JUST notice that problem happens on in Firefox 24 and Chrome and same thing works on IE 9

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Error 403 Empty page

Empty page

Guru Meditation:

XID: 1400950608

Varnish cache server
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Code make it work

```
<a href="http://href.li/?http://scores.itftennis.com/index.php?alias=itf&amp;layoutid=72&amp;versionid=1&amp;language=en&amp;tID=W-C75-UAE-01A-2013&amp;country=ISR" onclick="window.open('http://href.li/?http://scores.itftennis.com/index.php?alias=itf&amp;layoutid=72&amp;versionid=1&amp;language=en&amp;tID=W-C75-UAE-01A-2013&amp;country=ARE','W-C75-UAE-01A-2013','width=1000,height=680');return false;">LiveScores / Results</a>
```

Comment: Worth to mention the cause: that page is checking the referrer and if not their own domain it block the request, probably to prevent screen scraping. By using http://href.li/ you're hiding the referrer.

Comment: I agree with you. I found their installation Manual and it doesnt talk  about all this. They simply have mentioned that live scoring link can be added on external website. & to my surprise it was working on IE 9 but not FF or chrome... Couple of these issue just confused me. My first guess was they are checking the reference of website but i was not sure how to get around that... till i found `href.li`